# Появление окна

Tags: jquery, javascript

Очень понравилось, как появляется окно на этом сайте http://www.diplomtime.ru/ при нажатии "Заказать" или "Заказать обратный звонок". Но не могу понять, с чего начать.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как они на сайте используют [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/effect/), могу предположить, что это эффект "scale". [Смотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/kcb2pz4r/).